# Managing typescript references

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling a bit with a typescript project which has loads of references in the header of each file.

What I am finding is that I have at least 5-10 reference headers in the project I've not really found a good way of solving this as yet.

Basically I have a project laid out like this:

`app`

```
 app - views - html views

 app - viewModels - MVVM view models need to reference each other

 app - modules - modules used by various projects

 app - typings - using typelite to generate typescript files for project.
```

The files within need to reference each other. At present I have added references as and when I need them, but problems are sometimes hard to spot, I've resorted to using the command line typescript compiler to spot issues especially on compile and save.

I have considered defining a `reference.d.ts` file for each folder i.e. `views`, `viewModels`etc. So to reference a specific item in viewModels from I would need to add the Reference.d.ts only to the reference path header and not a lot of additional code.

I discovered this question which supports my theory of having a reference file per folder. Is there a better way of managing this?

[Typescript modules per folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779112/typescript-modules-per-folder)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at reference file generation : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#reference-file-generation

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a single references file with all the references in. Then you only needed to reference the reference file.

For example:

references.ts

```
/// <reference path="/app/views/viewA.ts" />
/// <reference path="/app/modules/moduleA.ts" />
/// <reference path="/app/modules/moduleB.ts" />
/// <reference path="/app/modules/moduleC.ts" />
```

moduleA.ts (and all the other files)

```
/// <reference path="../reference.ts" />
```

Of course, in Visual Studio 2013, you don't need any reference comments and if your program is going to get really big, external modules and a module loader can be a better option.

## Update for Visual Studio 2013 Update 3.

There have been some reports of files not being automatically included in auto-completion in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3. They should be automatically included if their build action is set to `TypeScriptCompile`.

Comment: Can you clarify your last paragraph? I'm in VS2013 and references don't seem to work for me unless I specify the references comments. And can you recommend a tutorial on how module loading provides Intellisense?

Comment: Sigh, that's a bummer. But maybe it's for the best, so that the dependencies are explicit.

Comment: Article updated - the `TypeScriptCompile` build action must be used to get the automatic behaviour.